# Spy on $rootScope.$on deregister function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-scope, spy

In my controller I'm watching $stateChangeStart on rootScope. When calling $on it returns a function that can be used to deregister the watcher. I'm trying to spy on this when the controller scope is destroyed. It's working in practice but unable to spy on it.

**Controller**

```
ctrl.deregister = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
    try {
        $modalInstance.close($modalInstance);
    } catch (err) { /* do nothing */ }
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', ctrl.deregister);
```

**Spec**

```
var scope;
var controller;
var ctrlDependencies;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller...) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    controller = $controller;
    ctrlDependencies = { /* deps */ };
});

it('should deregister rootScope watch on $destroy', function () {
    ctrl = controller('customExportController', ctrlDependencies);
    scope.$digest();

    spyOn(ctrl, 'deregister');

    scope.$destroy();
    expect(ctrl.deregister).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This test fails "Expected spy deregister to have been called." What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you define `scope` in the tests? My guess  is that the problem is somehow related. Perhaps the `scope` you are `$destroy`ing is not the one connected to the controller?

Comment: updated example to show more code

Comment: Are you passing in the $scope in as one of `ctrlDependencies`? I forget if it is names `scope` or `$scope`.